# How can I connect a dataset with the average of the values between two dates of another dataset in R?

Tags: r, date, merge, dataset

I want to connect two datasets with each other by adding a new column called  `Average`. This column is the average of the durations between `Date` and `Date - diff`. I got two datasets, the first one is called `data` and looks like this:

```
       Date   Weight   diff   Loc.nr  
2013-01-24     1040       7        2
2013-01-31     1000       7        2
2013-01-19      500       4        9
2013-01-23     1040       4        9
2013-01-28      415       5        9
2013-01-31      650       3        9
```

The other one is called `Rain.duration`, in the column `Duration` are the hours of rain on that day. This dataset looks like this:

```
      Date  Duration
2013-01-14       4.5
2013-01-15       0.0
2013-01-16       6.9
2013-01-17       0.0
2013-01-18       1.8
2013-01-19       2.1
2013-01-20       0.0
2013-01-21       0.0
2013-01-22       4.3
2013-01-23       0.0
2013-01-24       7.5
2013-01-25       4.7
2013-01-26       0.0
2013-01-27       0.7
2013-01-28       5.0
2013-01-29       0.0
2013-01-30       3.1
2013-01-31       2.8
```

I made a code to do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(Rain.duration)) {
    if(data$Date[i] == Rain.duration$Date[j]) {
      average <- as.array(Rain.duration$Duration[(j-(data$diff[i])):j])

      j <- nrow(Rain.duration)
    }
  }
  data$Average[i] <- mean(average)
}
```

The problem of this code is that, because of the size of my datasets, it takes like 3 days to run. Is there a faster way to do this?

My expected outcome is:

```
       Date   Weight   diff   Loc.nr   Average
2013-01-24     1040       7        2      1.96
2013-01-31     1000       7        2      2.98
2013-01-19      500       4        9      2.16
2013-01-23     1040       4        9      1.28
2013-01-28      415       5        9      2.98
2013-01-31      650       3        9      2.73
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading your code, but are you trying to get the average duration for each date? The averages you have in your expected output aren't the average duration for each date, but maybe that's just filler data?

Comment: I want the average of the interval between `Date` and `Date - diff` from `data`.

Comment: Im not understanding how `Weather` comes into play here. How is the `Duration` column related to what you're trying to calculate?

Comment: I just edited the question, but the `duration` is the number of hours of rain on that day. So I want to calculate the average number of hours of rain between the `data$Date` and `data$Date - data$diff`.

Comment: This sounds similar to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188807/23118), does any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# add row number as a new column just to make it easier to read
weather_with_rows  <- Weather %>%
    mutate(Rownum = row_number())

# write function to filter by row number, then return the average duration
getavgduration  <- function(mydate, mydiff) {

    myrow = weather_with_rows %>%
         filter(Date == mydate) %>%
         pluck("Rownum")

    mystartrow = myrow -mydiff

    myduration = weather_with_rows %>%
        filter(
              Rownum <= myrow
            , Rownum >= mystartrow
        )

    mean(myduration$Duration)

}

# get the average duration for each Date/diff pair
averages  <- data %>%
    group_by(Date, Diff) %>%
    summarize(Average = getavgduration(Date, Diff)) %>%
    ungroup()


# join this back into the original data frame
#    this step might not be necessary 
#    and might be a big drag on performance, 
#    depending on the size of your real data
data_with_avg_duration  <- data %>%
    left_join(averages, by = c('Date','Diff')
```

Comment: Than you for your solution. If I run this code I recieve an error at:
`averages  <- data %>%
    group_by(Date, diff) %>%
    summarize(Average = getavgduration(Date, diff)) %>%
    ungroup()`

The error says:
`Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : subscript out of bounds`
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I might have got the column names wrong, with regard to capitalization (or the duration column in the Weather df), inside the `getavgduration()` function. Looks like I capitalized "Date" in both data frames and did not capitalize "duration".

That error implies that a named column is not found and since R is case-sensitive, I might be missing something.

Comment: I edited my answer to make all the column names capitalized, consistently across both data frames.

Answer (score 0):

This old question does not have an accepted answer yet, so I feel obliged to post an alternative solution which *aggregates in a non-equi join*.

The OP has requested to compute the average duration of rain from a table `Rain.duration` of daily hours of rain fall for each date interval given in `data`.

```
library(data.table)
# make sure Date columns are of class Date
setDT(data)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
setDT(Rain.duration)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
# aggregate in a non-equi join and assign the result to a new column
data[,  Average := Rain.duration[data[, .(upper = Date, lower = Date - diff)], 
            on = .(Date <= upper, Date >= lower), 
            mean(Duration), by  = .EACHI]$V1][]
```

> ```
>          Date Weight diff Loc.nr  Average
> 1: 2013-01-24   1040    7      2 1.962500
> 2: 2013-01-31   1000    7      2 2.975000
> 3: 2013-01-19    500    4      9 2.160000
> 4: 2013-01-23   1040    4      9 1.280000
> 5: 2013-01-28    415    5      9 2.983333
> 6: 2013-01-31    650    3      9 2.725000
> ```

The key part is

```
Rain.duration[data[, .(upper = Date, lower = Date - diff)], 
              on = .(Date <= upper, Date >= lower), 
              mean(Duration), by  = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>          Date       Date       V1
> 1: 2013-01-24 2013-01-17 1.962500
> 2: 2013-01-31 2013-01-24 2.975000
> 3: 2013-01-19 2013-01-15 2.160000
> 4: 2013-01-23 2013-01-19 1.280000
> 5: 2013-01-28 2013-01-23 2.983333
> 6: 2013-01-28 2013-01-23 2.983333
> 7: 2013-01-31 2013-01-28 2.725000
> ```

which does a *non-equi join* with the date ranges derived from `data`:

```
data[, .(upper = Date, lower = Date - diff)]
```

> ```
>         upper      lower
> 1: 2013-01-24 2013-01-17
> 2: 2013-01-31 2013-01-24
> 3: 2013-01-19 2013-01-15
> 4: 2013-01-23 2013-01-19
> 5: 2013-01-28 2013-01-23
> 6: 2013-01-28 2013-01-23
> 7: 2013-01-31 2013-01-28
> ```

`by = .EACHI` requests to compute the aggregate `mean(Duration)` for each date interval *on-the-fly* which avoids to create and copy temporay subsets.

Note that this solution will give correct answers even if `Rain.duration` has gaps or is unordered as it relies only on `Date` as opposed to the other solutions which use row numbers.