# Linear interpolation in R for columns

Tags: r

I have a table with column called 'rates'. This column include missing values.
I need to calculate linear function where missing values are calculated based on previous existing value and a value that follows the missing value, and there should be an equal interval between replaced missing values.

For example, column 'rates' include values:
0,66
Na
Na
Na
0,77
0,75
0,79
Na
Na
0,79

And I need to get a new column where Na values will be replaced in R the way I described above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your effort so far. However, based on your question it seems that you just want the mean between the previous and next values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpolate NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188807/interpolate-na-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `na.approx` from the `zoo` package. The function according to document:

> Generic functions for replacing each NA with interpolated values.

Code:

```r
df <- data.frame(rates = c(0.66, NA, NA, NA, 0.77, 0.75, 0.79, NA, NA, 0.79))

library(zoo)
df$new_rates <- na.approx(df$rates)
df
#>    rates new_rates
#> 1   0.66    0.6600
#> 2     NA    0.6875
#> 3     NA    0.7150
#> 4     NA    0.7425
#> 5   0.77    0.7700
#> 6   0.75    0.7500
#> 7   0.79    0.7900
#> 8     NA    0.7900
#> 9     NA    0.7900
#> 10  0.79    0.7900
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>